# EmguCV and Unity3D Interoperation

Tags: opencv, unity-game-engine, emgucv

I managed integrating EmguCV into Unity3D and wrote a little converter that has some little problems

**Step 1** Converting Unity3D Texture to OpenCV Image

```
public static Image<Bgr, byte> UnityTextureToOpenCVImage(Texture2D tex){
    return UnityTextureToOpenCVImage(tex.GetPixels32 (), tex.width, tex.height);
}

public static Image<Bgr, byte> UnityTextureToOpenCVImage(Color32[] data, int width, int height){

    byte[,,] imageData = new byte[width, height, 3];


    int index = 0;
    for (int y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            imageData[x,y,0] = data[index].b;
            imageData[x,y,1] = data[index].g;
            imageData[x,y,2] = data[index].r;

            index++;
        }
    }

    Image<Bgr, byte> image = new Image<Bgr, byte>(imageData);

    return image;
}
```

**Step 2** Converting OpenCV Image back to Unity3D Texture

```
public static Texture2D OpenCVImageToUnityTexture(Image<Bgr, byte> openCVImage, GameObject check){
    return OpenCVImageToUnityTexture(openCVImage.Data, openCVImage.Width, openCVImage.Height, check);
}

public static Texture2D OpenCVImageToUnityTexture(byte[,,] data, int width, int height, GameObject check){

    Color32 [] imageData = new Color32[width*height];

    int index = 0;
    byte alpha = 255;

    for (int y = 0; y < width; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < height; x++) {
            imageData[index] = new Color32((data[x,y,2]),
                                           (data[x,y,1]),
                                           (data[x,y,0]),
                                           alpha);
            check.SetActive(true);
            index++;
        }
    }

    Texture2D toReturn = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGBA32, false);
    toReturn.SetPixels32(imageData);
    toReturn.Apply ();
    toReturn.wrapMode = TextureWrapMode.Clamp;

    return toReturn;
}
```

Compiler throws no errors but some goes wrong all the time. See yourself: [cats](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhRtT.png).
On the left side is the original image, on the right side is the converted one. As you can see there are more cats then it should be...
Has anyone any clues?

Also it is slow as hell because of iterating twice through all pixels. Is there any better solution?

**EDIT**

This is the code where i draw my GUITextures:

```
public GameObject catGO;

GUITexture guitex;
Texture catTex;

void Start () {
    guitex = GetComponent<GUITexture> ();
    catTex = catGO.GetComponent<GUITexture> ().texture;

    Image<Bgr, byte> cvImage = EmguCVUnityInterop.UnityTextureToOpenCVImage((Texture2D)catTex);

    Texture2D converted = EmguCVUnityInterop.OpenCVImageToUnityTexture(cvImage);
    guitex.texture = converted;
}
```

Comment: you should post the code that draws the gui texture... the problem could be there this looks fine.

Comment: EDIT: don't mind this comment...

Answer (score 0):

First of all you wrote in 2 for loops check.SetActive(true) so its width*height times. Enabling GameObject is a costly operation.

Second is that iterating thru every pixel is another costly operation. For examle if u have image 2560x1600 you have over 4 milion iterations.

Try to change TextureWrapMode to Repeat (I know it sounds silly:] )